How was the first continuous communication with LEO spacecraft established?
In the Apollo era, spacecraft had only intermittent contact with mission control as their communication link was “handed off” from the US to South Africa to Australia during the spacecraft’s LEO portion of the mission.
Which was the first LEO crewed spaceflight that had continuous contact with mission control for the entire orbit and how was this achieved?


Which was the first LEO crewed spaceflight that had continuous contact with mission control for the entire orbit and how was this achieved?

Certainly not Apollo or Skylab, or even early Space Shuttle flights. The orbiting vehicles back then only had communications with the Earth when they were within range of a ground station.
The Tracking and Data Relay Satellites (TDRS) were what enabled continuous contact. The first such satellite was deployed from STS-6. Several more were deployed from subsequent Shuttle flights; one was lost with the Challenger disaster.
At least three TDRS satellites are needed to provide continuous coverage. The Zone of Exclusion (ZOE) above the Indian and eastern Pacific oceans precluded completely continuous coverage. The ZOE was closed in the mid to late 1990s, partly through the construction of the Guam Remote Ground Terminal , which was declared operational in 1998.

The early ISS continued to have periods without data when dropping off of one TDRS and waiting for the next.  That might have changed more recently.

That was a sad day for the Control Center when they closed the ZOE. No more potty or coffee breaks when the data went static.
